# FROM_UNIXTIME() and PHP strtotime()

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, epoch

I have a string:

12/27/2012 04:00 am

The string is converted to epoch using strtotime() which yields:

```
1356609600
```

Then when this is called:

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(1356609600);
```

I see the output has the time truncated. Does anyone know why the time has been truncated or how to retain the time from this type of conversion:

```
2012-12-27 12:00:00
```

Comment: Presumably you have the timezone set differently for PHP and MySQL.  I suggest setting them both to UTC to avoid exactly this sort of confusion (do timezone conversions when needed for display etc).

Answer (score 4):

No time is truncated here. `12/27/2012 04:00 am` is assumed local time by `strtotime`. When its converted to mysql,  mysql sets the time in the local timezone. Now **if your timezone settings on Mysql and php differ then it'll not show same time.**

For PHP set [`date.timezone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) in `php.ini` and set [`default-time-zone`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html) in `my.cnf` or `my.ini`

For example, my time zone is `Asia/Dhaka`. I set it in both php.ini and my.cnf

#### php.ini

```
date.timezone = Asia/Dhaka
```

#### my.cnf

```
default-time-zone = 'Asia/Dhaka'
```

Comment: Yes. I actually just used a converter and much to my surprise it just so happened to 4:00am converted to 12:00:00 in GMT. I will be accepting this post as the correct answer. Thank you.